# Include an interface into a class in a .d.ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a JavaScript class that extends the instance with constructor options:

```
class C {
  constructor(options) {
    Object.assign(this, options)
  }
}
```

That means that the class instance is going to have all of the properties of the `options` object.

I'm looking for a way to write a .d.ts definition for that class without duplicating interface properties:

```
interface Options {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
}

class C {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;

  constructor(options: Options);
}
```

Is there a way to include all of the `Options` interface properties? Tried the following, but that's not valid TypeScript:

```
class C {
  ...Options;

  constructor(options: Options);
}
```

Comment: Can't you do use of ```extend```? Like ```class C extends Options {..}```

Comment: what @KeyboardCorporation said, in a tutorial: "How to Extend Interfaces in TypeScript" https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-extend-interface/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, you can achieve this by using the intersection type `(&)`. You can create an interface that represents the class properties and then intersect it with the Options interface. Here's how you can do it:

```
interface Options {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
}

interface C extends Options {}

class C {
  constructor(options: Options) {
    Object.assign(this, options);
  }
}

// Example usage
const instance = new C({ foo: 42, bar: "hello" });
console.log(instance.foo); // 42
console.log(instance.bar); // "hello"
```

In this example, the `C` class extends the `Options` interface, which means it inherits all the properties of the `Options` interface. The `constructor` function then enforces that the `options` parameter must conform to the `Options` interface.

This way, you avoid duplicating the property definitions in both the `Options` interface and the `C` class. If you add or remove properties from the `Options` interface, the `C` class will automatically reflect those changes.

Comment: Declaring `interface C extends Options {}` does the trick. Thank you!